# How to optimize this code (C#)

Tags: unity, c#

Could someone help me optimize my code below . I'm not satisfied with this though it gets what i want and execute what i want.

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject CameraScriptsAir_1,CameraScripstAir_2;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] CameraScriptsTV;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] TwoScript;

[SerializeField]
GameObject[] Tests;

[SerializeField]
GameObject FogEffect;

void Update()
{
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW == false)
    {
        CameraScriptsAir_1 = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        CameraScripstAir_2 = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(2).gameObject;

        CameraScriptsTV[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(5).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        CameraScriptsTV[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(6).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        CameraScriptsTV[2] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(7).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        TwoScript[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(8).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).gameObject;
        TwoScript[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(38).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        //29
        Tests[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(9).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(10).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[2] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(11).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[3] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(12).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[4] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(13).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[5] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(14).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[6] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(15).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[7] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(16).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[8] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(17).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[9] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(18).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[10] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(19).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[11] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(20).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[12] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(21).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[13] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(22).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[14] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(23).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[15] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(24).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[16] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(25).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[17] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(26).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[18] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(27).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[19] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(28).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[20] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(29).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[21] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(30).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[22] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(31).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[23] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(32).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[24] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(33).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[25] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(34).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[26] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(35).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[27] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(36).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        Tests[28] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(37).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        //fog
        FogEffect = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).GetChild(0).GetChild(2).gameObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what for loops are?

Comment: @Bálint I know what it is but i don't know how to implement it sir.

Comment: Then maybe start with learning programming. Don't jump into unity without that

Comment: @NoobProgrammer I've answered your question  to give you an example but your question is not very clear as to what you are trying to achieve, provide more information so I can help you better. As mentioned you should probably learn some programming first before you jump into unity!

Comment: I get the idea . Thank you . Though its a lil bit too far from there. Still i got the idea so thank you very much @Valamorde

Comment: @NoobProgrammer no problem!

Comment: By the way, we also have https://codereview.stackexchange.com - a stackexchange site specifically for getting constructive feedback for code you wrote.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer You have accepted an answer, but you haven't finished clarifying what you're doing for the answer to truly be THE answer. Why are you traversing an object hierarchy in that manner? What is the hierarchy of in the first place? In order for a question to have value to other people, you have to clearly state the problem you are trying to solve, not just an obscure code snippit.

Comment: @Stephan what i am trying to do here sir is that i need to get the game object through `getchild()` and then access the gameobject component that has been get by using the `getchild` and disable the script `bloom.cs` and `depthoffield.cs` that is what i'm trying to achieve here. I'm using get child so that i don't need to drag/apply it from hierarchy to the component.

Comment: Does the parent object have more than one copy of bloom and depthoffield? If not you can use getcomponent<bloom> to shortcut so you don't run the risk of your indexes ending up out of bounds or other than expected. This is why an image of your object hierarchy is important to include with the question.

Comment: Please see the image : [Image Reference](https://imgur.com/a/jNnHx) . Only the Camera GameObject is what I'm aiming. So if i use the `getcomponent<bloom>` to get all all the bloom then also the other camera from my horse,camera,env will also be there so that's not what i am aiming for . Only for the Camera GameObject.

Comment: You would be better off putting this script directly on the Camera GameObject in that case, or you could expose a `GameObject` parameter that you can then drag your camera object onto and reference it directly - that way `GetComponent` (or [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)) would be limited to just that branch of the tree - if you accidentally move the camera in the hierarchy, this script will break horribly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (and should) use a for loop, for example this:

```
    Tests[0] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(9).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[1] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(10).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[2] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(11).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[3] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(12).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[4] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(13).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[5] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(14).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[6] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(15).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[7] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(16).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[8] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(17).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[9] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(18).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[10] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(19).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[11] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(20).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[12] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(21).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[13] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(22).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[14] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(23).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[15] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(24).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[16] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(25).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[17] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(26).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[18] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(27).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[19] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(28).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[20] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(29).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[21] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(30).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[22] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(31).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[23] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(32).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[24] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(33).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[25] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(34).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[26] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(35).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[27] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(36).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
    Tests[28] = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(37).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

could be simplified to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<29; i++)
{
    Tests[i]= this. transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(i+9).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject; //what are you trying to get here???? this still is not right!
}
```